# Overloading conversion function templates

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution, conversion-operator

Consider the following:

```
struct X {
    template <class T> operator T();  // #1
    template <class T> operator T&(); // #2
};

int        a = X{}; // error: ambiguous
int&       b = X{}; // calls #2
int const& c = X{}; // calls #2
```

The situation for `b` is straightforward, `#2` is the only viable candidate. What is the rule that indicates that `#2` is preferred to `#1` for initialization of `int const&`, but the two are ambiguous for initialization of `int`?

Comment: [\[over.match.conv\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.conv) and [\[over.match.ref\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ref) seem like a good starting point.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Those sections indicate what the candidate functions are. Not how to prefer (or not) one or the other.

Comment: the templating is not essential here, plain `operator int` and `operator int&` also are ambiguous

Comment: "Those non-explicit conversion functions that ... yield type “lvalue reference to cv2 T2” (when initializing an lvalue reference ...) where “cv1 T” is reference-compatible ([dcl.init.ref]) with “cv2 T2”, are candidate functions" seems to indicate to me a restriction for initializing lvalue types that would disqualify #1 for `int const&`

Comment: @TemplateRex I guess that adds another followup question about `operator T&` and `operator T const&`, which is nonambiguous is one case where the non-template versions are ambiguous.

Comment: @TemplateRex Yes, but what's the deal with `c`?

Comment: @TemplateRex I know it's unambiguous. The question is why is `a` ambiguous but not `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deciding how to initialize a reference given its initializer, first, direct binding is tried. [[dcl.init.ref]/(5.1.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5):

> If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression […] has a class type (i.e., `T2` is a class type), where `T1` is not reference-related to `T2`, and can be
>   converted to an lvalue of type “*cv3* `T3`”, where “*cv1* `T1`” is reference-compatible with “*cv3* `T3`” (**this conversion is selected by enumerating the applicable conversion functions (13.3.1.6) and choosing the best one through overload resolution (13.3)**), then the reference is bound […] to the lvalue result
>   of the conversion […].

The wording that governs the candidate selection for this process ([13.3.1.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ref#1), as mentioned above) excludes the first conversion function:

> The conversion functions of `S` and its base classes are considered. **Those non-explicit conversion functions
>   that are not hidden within `S` and yield type “lvalue reference to *cv2* `T2`”**(when initializing an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference to function) […], where “*cv1* `T`” is reference-compatible (8.6.3)
>   with “*cv2* `T2`”, **are candidate functions**. For direct-initialization, […].

Clearly, this exclusion is specific to the reference initialization semantics, so the first case is ambiguous still.

Comment: But you omitted the part of the section that considers conversion functions that yield *cv2* `T2`. What happened to that other candidate function?

Comment: @Barry doesn't that only apply to "initializing an rvalue reference or an lvalue reference to function", or am I missing your meaning?

Comment: @jaggedSpire I was gonna say, barry confused me for a second. If a conversion function returns a prvalue, how can an lvalue reference bind directly to it? That would kinda miss the point of that section.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was missing. So the reason that `operator T()` is a candidate isn't because 13.3.1.6 says it is, but because we fallback to 8.6.3/5.2.2.1 and 13.3.1.5 finds it. Right?

Comment: @Barry A candidate in what situation?

Comment: @Columbo In `int const& c = X{}`. Assuming `operator T&()` didn't exist. Perhaps candidate is the wrong word, since the two aren't considered at the same time in the way overload resolution typically works.